# Challenging Location Matching API Facebook -> Foursquare

Tags: facebook-graph-api, foursquare

I have a challenging location matching API problem and would appreciate if any Facebook & Foursquare API expert here can help. How do one match a particular place in Facebook Graph API to the place in Foursquare Venue API?

```
Given inputs: 
- id of place in Facebook GRAPH API
Wanted output:
- id or any identity of the exact place in FourSqure Venue
```

For example, a place called Starbuck@RaffleCity has id 123 in Facebook graph search, how do you find that place in FourSquare?

One solution I can think of is to use the Name of that place get from Facebook graph API as a string search in Foursquare Venue api, but that won't gaurantee the correct place 100%. Starbuck@RaffleCity search input to foursquare venue api doesn't give me the correct result.

Tried solution: use lat and long. also didn't work because one lat long can match to many places.

Comment: Please bear in mind Foursquare API "Venues Database Usage" policies if you find an adequate solution: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community

"You can associate additional content with our venue data in your system, but you may not combine our database with another database"